# Laravel sort conversations by last message

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have a `Conversation` model that has many `ConversationMessage` models.

Now I want to sort the conversations based on the last message of the conversation. Basically like WhatsApp. How do I build the query?

As a sidenote to my code: Conversation contains a user (`user_id`)
and a company associated (`company_id`). Company has a `belongsToMany` relation to user.

```
Conversation::whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->whereHas('users', function ($q1) use ($userId) {
        $q1->where('users.id', $userId);
    });
})->orWhereHas('user', function($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->where('user.id', $userId);
})->with(array('conversationMessage' => function($q) {
    $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
})->get();
```

That sort the `ConversationMessage` relation models but not the conversations. How can I sort the `Conversations` based on the last message?

Comment: before anything, I'm not sure but I think you can write your first `whereHas` in one line: `Conversation::whereHas('company.users', function ($q) use ($userId) {
    $q->where('users.id', $userId);
})`

Comment: Thats True, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a `timestamp` field like `last_message_at` to your `Conversations` model and when a new message is added to that `Conversation` update that field, then later you can sort the result based on `last_message_at`.

Or you can filter results in the query like below(Test it see if it works):

```
    Conversation::whereHas('company', function ($q) use ($userId) {
        $q->whereHas('users', function ($q1) use ($userId) {
            $q1->where('users.id', $userId);
        });
    })->orWhereHas('user', function($q) use ($userId) {
        $q->where('user.id', $userId);
    })->with(array('conversationMessage' => function($q) {
        $q->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC');
    })
    ->selectRaw("conversations.*, (SELECT MAX(created_at) from conversation_messages WHERE conversation_messages.conversation_id=conversations.id) as latest_message_on")
    ->orderBy("latest_message_on", "DESC")
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thats an option I was thinking about too, but that would be a update query at every new message. Personaly I would find it better to just sort on the relation, if it is possible

Comment: Here is an update to the answer, test it see if it works.