# How to sort Laravel eloquent result by another table column

Tags: laravel

I have a very simple chat application which have 3 tables users , chat_rooms and chats table for sotring every users messages.

I want to show chat rooms in a box in my view but i want them to be sorted by messages created_at so that the chat rooms that have newest messages be on the top.

the query that i use is

```
ChatRoom::with('user')
            ->join('chats','chat_rooms.room_id','chats.room_id')
            ->select('chat_rooms.*','chats.created_at as c','chats.message')
            ->orderBy('c','DECS')
            ->paginate(5);
```

this works fine but returns all chats i tried to use `groupBy('room_id')` on my query but then  it stoped working

i could use collections methods to fix this but then i could not use pagination and i realy dont want to use collection methods in this case.

**note that im using laravel 5.4**

Comment: does chats table have relationship with users as well?

Comment: why are you using group by if you want to sort by another column?

Comment: @AhmadKarimi yes it does.

Comment: @IGP because i want show chat rooms with new messages in top. like  WhatsApp or any other messenger that shows the groups with new messages on top of other groups.

Comment: After hours of searching i found this topic with same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691561/laravel-sort-conversations-by-last-message

Comment: So for now, your problem is that the query retrieves all the chats instead of only 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your eloquent pagination run on ChatRoom table Not on messages.
So you can try another ways to load your message under chatroom.

- If you have a lot of chatroom and want to paginate both chatroom and their messages, you can paginate chatroom (without join to messages) and run eloquent for each chatroom messages separately.
- you can also use lazy load for messages on view but you must control messages paginate yourself

-------------EDITED-------------

Show chatroom with new messages:

Laravel <6

```
ChatRoom::select(['chat_rooms.*', 'chats.created_at as c'])
            ->join(DB::raw("(SELECT chats.room_id, max(chats.created_at) as created_at
                FROM chats
                GROUP BY room_id
                ORDER BY created_at DESC
                ) as chats"), function ($join) {
                $join->on("chat_rooms.id", "=", "chats.room_id");
            })
            ->orderBy('c', 'DECS')
            ->paginate(5);
```

Laravel >=6

```
$chatQuery = Chat::selectRaw("chats.room_id, max(chats.created_at) as created_at")
            ->groupBy("chats.room_id")
            ->orderBy("created_at", "desc");

ChatRoom::select(['chat_rooms.*', 'chats.created_at as c'])
  ->joinSub($chatQuery, 'chats', function ($join) {
       $join->on('chat_rooms.id', '=', 'chats.room_id');
  })
  ->orderBy('c','DECS')
  ->paginate(5);
```

Comment: thanks for your response but i just want paginate chatrooms sorted by new message so that the chatrooms with new messages be on top of others like WhatsApp or telegram.

Comment: yw, i have edited my answer with laravel eloquent to show only chatroom with new messages @MardeKhiky

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to sort by a column after the first orderBy, just add another orderBy. If you were to use groupBy in that query you would lose most of the messages.

```
->orderByDesc('c')
->orderBy('room_id')
->paginate(5);
```